# Left eigenvector of the product of matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, and their corresponding left-eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $1$ as $\mathbf w_1$ and $\mathbf w_2$.

$\mathbf w_1^TA_1=\mathbf w_1^T$ and $\mathbf w_2^TA_2=\mathbf w_2^T$.

I have matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ with right eigenvectors as $\mathbf{a}>0$, with eigenvalue $1$. Which is why the product also has the same right eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

So, I have $A_1\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}$ and $A_2\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}$, which implies $A_2A_1\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}$.

Is there a way to find left eigenvector of the product $A_2A_1$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$ in terms of $\mathbf w_1$ and $\mathbf w_2$?

Comment: I think you're hoping for too much here. There's no reason to believe that $A_2A_1$ also has eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: I have matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ with right eigenvectors as $\mathbf{a}$, with eigenvalue $1$. Which is why the product has the eigenvalue 1.

Comment: *“Is there a way”* is vague. Of course there is a way, such as to solve the homogeneous linear equation $x^T(I-A_2A_1)=0$. But if you mean to express the left eigenvector of $A_2A_1$ only in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$, I don't think this is in general possible.

Comment: In general, the eigenvalue of a product of matrices is not the product of its eigenvalues. You don't seem convinced so I hope this concrete example will convince you. Let $A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\\end{bmatrix}$ and $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @user1551, yes I want to find the eigenvectors in terms of $\mathbf w_1$ and $\mathbf w_2$.

Comment: @daruma I have added extra information of same right eigenvector for $A_1$ and $A_2$ which makes it possible to have the eigenvalue $1$ for the product $A_1A_2$. see $A_1A_2\mathbf a=A_1\mathbf a=\mathbf a$ meaning that $1$ is the the eigenvalue of matrix $A_1A_2$.

Comment: If you want to find a left eigenvector of $A_2A_1$ corresponding to the unit eigenvalue in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$, this is impossible in general. Consider e.g. the case where
$$
A_2=\pmatrix{1&v^T\\ 0&0},\ A_1=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&X},
\ A_2A_1=\pmatrix{1&v^TX\\ 0&0}.
$$
where $I-X$ is invertible. Then $1$ is a simple eigenvalue of $A_2,A_1$ and $A_2A_1$. Hence, up to scaling, we have $w_2^T=(1,v^T)$, $w_1^T=(1,0)$ and the left eigenvector of $A_2A_1$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ is $y^T=(1,v^TX)$. Clearly one cannot express $v^TX$ in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$ only.

Comment: You have a nonnegative right eigenvector and I believe that another restriction on right eigenvector $\mathbf a>0$ will also make it difficult to find the eigenvector for $A_2A_1$. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear. But here is a possible solution,

Suppose $A_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$,$A_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$ and $a=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}$

$$A_{1}a=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}aa_{1}+ba_{2}\\ca_{1}+da_{2}\end{pmatrix}=a=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A_{2}a=\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ea_{1}+fa_{2}\\ga_{1}+ha_{2}\end{pmatrix}=a=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A_{1}A_{2}a=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}(ae+bg)+a_{2}(af+bh)\\a_{1}(ce+dg)+a_{2}(cf+dh)\end{pmatrix}=a=\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

From the above relations and Equating the corresponding terms, we'll get some equations. And, as if you have put two more conditions

$$w_{1}^{T}A_{1}=w_{1}^{T}\;and \;w_{2}^{T}A_{2}=w_{2}^{T}$$

In similar manner, assume w_{1} and w_{2}. Then,put in the relation and equate corresponding terms, you'll again get some equations.

After solving all equations, you'll get your desired answer.